# How to resolve Paypal(2.1.0) live environment error code 589009 in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, paypal, payment-gateway

I am using latest paypal(2.1.0) which works fine in simulator and showing error with error code 589009 in device.How to solve this error?

error code: 589009

error message:The payment can not be processed because no payment source is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am also facing the same issue....I integrated with the latest MPL 2.1.0, when i am testing in sandbox it is working fine. When i test in device with live mode it is giving me an error.

error code: 589009
error message:The payment can not be processed because no payment source is available

Comment: I received response from PayPal... Hello Sudheer,

Thank you for contacting PayPal Merchant Technical Support.

This appears to be a standard payment decline and not a code based issue.

Please verify the funding method attached to your account and attempt to complete your payment again.

Thank you!